# TypeError: count is not a function in node.js and sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm following [the Node.js + Express tutorial from the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Home_page), but I'm using MySQL with [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize).

I'm getting the error on `Model.count()` call:

> TypeError: Book.count is not a function
>      at bookCount (D:\node-apps\express-library\controllers\bookController.js:9:12)

The following is the code from `controllers/bookController.js`. The error is triggered from the line `Book.count().then(callback);`.

```
var Book = require('../models/book');
var Author = require('../models/author');

var async = require('async');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  async.parallel({
    bookCount: function(callback) {
      Book.count().then(callback);
    },
    authorCount: function(callback) {
      Author.count().then(callback);
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
    res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library', error: err, data: results });
  });
};
```

I debugged `console.log(Book)` and it returns `[function]`. The following is `models/book.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    summary: DataTypes.STRING,
    isbn: DataTypes.STRING,
    url: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});

  Book.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Book.belongsTo(models.Author, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
    Book.hasMany(models.BookInstance);
    Book.belongsToMany(models.Genre, {
      through: 'BookGenres',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };

  return Book;
};
```

Comment: Many downvotes ever I received :) I don't have enough experience in sequelize. Sorry for my bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this module script `models/index.js`:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

So, I replaced these two require statements

```
var Book = require('../models/book');
var Author = require('../models/author');
```

with

```
var models = require("../models");
```

then, calling `models.Book.count()` and `models.Author.count()` solved the problem.

```
var async = require('async');
var models = require('../models');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  async.parallel({
    bookCount: function(callback) {
      models.Book.count().then(count => {
        callback(null, count);
      });
    },
    authorCount: function(callback) {
      models.Author.count().then(count => {
        callback(null, count);
      });
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library', error: err, data: results });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the  `models/book.js` you export a function, which returns the Book model, not the model itself.

So when you write...

```
var Book = require('../models/book');
```

...you get a function stored in the `Book` variable. To get the model itself, you should run that function:

```
var Book = require('../models/book'); // that will be a function
var BookModel = Book(sequelize, dataTypes); // and that will be the model
```

Or you can run that functions right in your require statements:

```
var Book = require('../models/book')(sequelize, dataTypes);
var Author = require('../models/author')(sequelize, dataTypes);
```

Comment: I added my own answer. Thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing sequelize models incorrectly.

```
            var Book = sequelize.import('../models/Book');
        //note that the 'sequelize' is instance of sequelize and not Constructor.
```

You may also want to match table name from model definition, in your case 
'Book' and not 'book', because your model definition defines 'Book'

Ref - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#import

Comment: I added my own answer. Thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting, `Model.count()`, is similar to mine.

Mine was "**`Post.count()` is not a function**":

[image]

I found that it should be:

```
        Post.countDocuments();
```

Hope that would help.